# RavenDb v3 index on neasted fields

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

Is it possible to create neasted field index ( on field **t5**) using ravendb studio?

```
 {
        "p": 297641,
        "t1": {
            "t2": [
                {
                    "t3": {
                        "t4": {
                            "t5": "I would like index that field"
                        }
                    },
                    "nr_czesci": 3,
                    "waluta": "PLN"
                },
                {
                    "t3": {
                        "t4": {
                            "t5": "I would like index that field 2"
                        }
                    },
                    "nr_czesci": 4,
                    "waluta": "PLN"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, you can do it like this:

```
   from d in docs.YourCollections
   select new
   {
      t5 = t1.t2.Select(a => a.t3.t4.t5 )
   }
```